# Can't execute YUIcompressor globally using Path environments (Windows XP)!

Tags: java, windows-xp, yui-compressor

I typed `D:\yuicompressor-2.42\build` in Path and save it (Windows XP). But when I tried executing it the command line displayed: unable to access jarfile. The same message that appear when I type an incorrect directory.

I tried executing the file in this way:

```
D:\wamp\www\projects\alexchen\alexchen 0.1\scripts>java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar custom.js -o custom.min.js
```

[according to this](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/minify-javascript-css-yui-compressor/)

I tried calling the file directly and it works:

```
D:\wamp\www\projects\alexchen\alexchen 0.1\scripts>java -jar D:\yuicompressor-2.4.2\build\yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar custom.js -o custom.min.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you've misread the docs:

> It's simple to use, as shown in the following example. Replace /path/to with the actual path to the YUI Compressor, yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar with the actual version you are using, common.js with your input filename and common.min.js with the name you want the output file to be:
>
> java -jar /path/to/yuicompressor-2.4.2.jar common.js -o common.min.js

This means that you should specify full path to your jar file, not to put it in the Path env variable.

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute a JAR file with `java -jar` you'll need to specify the full path to the JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

```
java -cp "<path to jar file dir>" -jar "<jarfilename>" args
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can create an enviroment variable that contains the absolute path to your yuicompressor-x.y.z.jar and even include the filename! This then could act as a placeholder or text-expander-like-makro.

So if, for example, your variable was named "yuicompressor" you could call this one instead of always having to enter the full path over and over again.

```
java -jar %yuicompressor% myFile.js -o myFile.min.js --charset utf-8
```